# jqGrid - prevent deselecting of a row

Tags: select, jqgrid

Using jqGrid, if I click the selected row again, the row is deselected.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?
I would like the row to still be selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a workaround my brother and I came up with, just place the following code in the beforeSelectRow event:

```
  beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
      if ($(this).getGridParam('selrow') == rowid) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping to see when I clicked this! +10  :)

Answer (score 7):

Great solution, a little bit more compact version:

```
  beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
      return ($(this).getGridParam('selrow') != rowid);
  }
```