# jqgrid is row in edit mode

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is there a way to know if a row inside the jqgrid is in edit mode?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you speak about rows in inline editing mode than you can vertify whether row (`<tr>` element) has attribute `editable="1"`. The attribute will be set ba jqGrid for all rows which are in the editing mode. So the code could be

```
if ($("tr#"+rowid).attr("editable") === "1") {
    // the row having id=rowid is in editing mode
}
```

or

```
$($("#list").jqGrid("getInd",rowid,true)).attr("editable") === "1") {
    // the row having id=rowid is in editing mode
}
```

Comment: thank's! when i'm selecting a row it goes in edit mode , is there a way to disable unselecting this row when clicking it again, (while it is in edit mode)?

Comment: @ : Yes, it is possible. You should use `beforeSelectRow` to prevent unselecting. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921141/jqgrid-prevent-deselecting-of-a-row/4921458#4921458 for details.

Comment: The selector 'tr#id' can be written more simply as '#id' as ids are unique. (And it will be faster.)

Comment: @Vroo: `'tr#colName'` is better as `'#colName'` (more safe) because jqGrid can produce **id duplicates**. For example if you have two grids on the page and both grids have column with the same name `colName`. If you use form editing in both grids (by `navGrid` for example) and the user first opens Add/Edit form. It creates element with `id="colName"`. After the user close the form of the first grid the form will be **hidden**. On opening of the Add/Edit form of the second grid one will have one more DOM element with `id="colName"`. `'#colName'` get element of *the first* hidden grid.

Comment: @Oleg: thanks for the comment. Note that this is row id, not column id, which really should be unique as lots of jqgrid code I've seen will fail and duplicate ids are invalid html anyway. 

For the example you cite, 'tr#colName', I don't see how adding the 'tr' qualifier helps. Won't the forms in both cases be tr elements? Wouldn't something like $('#colName', someContext) be needed?

Comment: @Vroo: Sorry, I read the old question not carefully. You are right: `tr` part of `$("tr#"+rowid)` selector get no advantage and `$("#"+rowid)` can be used instead. In more common case (if id can contains [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)) the usage of `$("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(rowid))` or `$("#list").jqGrid("getGridRowById", rowid)`. If you are sure that there are no id duplicates on the page and `rowid` contains no meta-characters `$("#"+rowid)` will be the best choice.